# UIWebView content doesn't load until after view is shown

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiwebview, uikit

I have a `UIView` which, on `viewDidLoad` creates and shows a `UIWebView`.  The web view doesn't actually show its contents until the view has actually appeared though. The navigation bar appears with the view during its animation process but the web view is populated a second after the animation has finished.  How can I make the web view load the contents BEFORE animation begins.  Here is my code, thanks:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = @"Help";
    NSString *html = @"my html contents goes here, all local and all within a string - does contain one BG image though";

    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:_webFrame];
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithpath:path];

    [webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:baseURL];
    [self.view addSubView:webView];
    [webView release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a `UIWebView` needs some time to initialize, since it uses the WebKit engine.
You could try adding a simple timeout before actually pushing the new viewcontroller or show a placeholder during the 'push' animation.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, a UIWebView has to be on screen in order to load and render.
i'd try the following:

1. create and add web view on the calling view controller.
2. set frame of the web view in a way only one pixel is shown on screen.
3. load html content.
4. push to new ViewController, remove Web View from old parent and add to new one.

might work, but it's really not worth the hassle, why not try to "solve" the issue by adding a load indicator or a placeholder text?